# Flexbox not working when trying to draw a 9 element grid

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to use Flexbox to get a 3 by 3 grid of elements.

Here's what I have:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap"
      }}
    >
      {Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, index) => (
        <div
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            height: 200,
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            margin: 4,
            width: 150
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: distracted-wing-plyl7f]

This renders the following:

[image: img1]

However, this is what I would like to do:

[image: img2]

What am I doing wrong here? I have to use Flexbox, I can't use Grid, and I've tried to make use of `flex-wrap`, but it doesn't seem to work, even if I specify a value for the width of a card.

Comment: if you cant use grid for whatever reason, you have to calculate the width of those child elements which also includes the gaps as flexbox unlike grid does not subtract the gaps on its own

Comment: `flex: 1` "expands" to `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%;`

Comment: Why can't you use grid? This is specifically what css grid is made for. Alternatively, try a table.

Comment: @DustInComp I'm using React-Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code sets up a Flexbox container with elements displayed in a row with flexWrap: "wrap", but to achieve a 3 by 3 grid, you need to make a few adjustments. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        width: "450px", // Set a specific width to limit the number of items per row
      }}
    >
      {Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{
            flex: "1 0 calc(33.333% - 8px)", // 33.333% width with 8px margin
            height: "200px",
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            margin: "4px",
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the modified code:

1. I set a specific width for the flex container (width: "450px") to limit the number of items per row to three. Adjust this width as needed.
2. I added a unique key to each element in the map to satisfy React's requirement for keys when rendering lists of elements.
3. I adjusted the flex property to distribute the items evenly, and I used calc to account for the margins and ensure there are three items per row.

These changes should give you a 3 by 3 grid of elements using Flexbox. You can adjust the width and other styles to match your design requirements.